# Loop through checkboxes, textboxes and labels

Tags: c#, foreach

Esentially I'm trying to turn the below code into a loop. Every time I try to iterate through controls I seem to hit some sort of dead end and can't figure out how to update the relevant label or check the relevant textbox.

```
if (checkBox1.Checked && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
    if (RemoteFileExists(textBox1.Text) == true)
    {
        label1.Text = "UP";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "DOWN";
    }
}

if (checkBox2.Checked && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text))
{
    if (RemoteFileExists(textBox2.Text) == true)
    {
        label2.Text = "UP";
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text = "DOWN";
    }
}

if (checkBox3.Checked && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
{
    if (RemoteFileExists(textBox3.Text) == true)
    {
        label3.Text = "UP";
    }
    else
    {
        label3.Text = "DOWN";
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand what is your problem...

Comment: What exactly you want????

Comment: Re think. Use Tag, extend the controls. Just think how much has to stay in step for this to keep working, and how are you going to test this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Form.Controls` to iterate all the controls on the page, so for example:

```
foreach(Control control in Controls) {
   if (control is Checkbox) {
       ...
   } else if (control is TextBox) {
       ...
   } else {
       ...
   }
}
```

However, this will do ALL controls so might not be efficient. You might be able to use the `Tag` of your controls and LINQ extensions to improve it, for example:

```
IEnumerable<Checkbox> needed_checkboxes = Controls.Where(control => control is Checkbox && control.Tag == someValue);
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning Tag, or any other decoupling method. Using Control Names like this is asking for a maintenance nightmare

Comment: I've always done `if (control.GetType() == typeof(object))`.  This is much easier to read. :)

Comment: I'll have to go off and learn to do this a bit better but I'll give it a shot.  Thanks a lot, really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it by finding the controls dynamically:

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                CheckBox chbx = (CheckBox) this.FindControl("checkBox" + i);
                TextBox txtb = (TextBox)this.FindControl("textBox" + i);
                Label lbl = (Label) this.FindControl("label" + i);
                if (chbx.Checked && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtb.Text))
                {
                    if (RemoteFileExists(txtb.Text) == true)
                    {
                        lbl.Text = "UP";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lbl.Text = "DOWN";
                    }
                }
            }
```